# WordPress wp_options has grown too big

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress/woocommerce store and I am trying to clean things up a bit as it is very sluggish on the backend.

While investigating I found that my wp_options table alone is over 550 MB in size.So how can i reduce the size.

- I used clean up using SQL queries but didn't reduce.
- I used many plugin for that like as plugin garbage collector,Wp sweep,WP optimize etc.

Its good if anyone help me out this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Reinstall wordpress..

Comment: Thanks for reply but i know this way but its good if i do reduce without Reinstall.so any idea?

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1CDGOYI_enIL695IL695&hl=en-US&biw=320&bih=492&ei=nO9uWfegNsT_Uuf3n-AD&q=cleanup+wp_options&oq=cleanup+wp_&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.0i22i30k1l3j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1.479412.489106.0.490542.22.22.0.5.5.0.650.3992.0j18j2j5-1.21.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..10.11.1158.0..0j0i67k1j0i10i67k1j0i131k1j0i10k1._I5C9fkK1Aw

Comment: I have been did google search.

Comment: Hard to believe, because the answer is in the first result.

Comment: Yes but i have did. :(

Comment: Did you go through this https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-cleanup-the-wp-options-table-in-wordpress/ ?

Comment: yes same but didn't reduce and also check many blogs related to WordPress wp_options has grown too big.

Comment: The first of all sorry and second of all, how many plugins do you have installed? Maybe it's actually needed data..

Comment: Website have 40 plugin installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149546/discussion-between-arpan-sagar-and-evgenykolyakov).

Comment: Hhhh... then what do you expect? It's a lot of data... I'd guess that you have a plugin or two taking most of this place... try to determine the largest plugins and decide whether to remove or replace them...

Comment: Ok thanks for that so will try.